# Is there anything like PostfixIcon for TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've already tried PrefixIcon for TextField in flutter but this time I'm looking for something like Postfix Clickable Icon in flutter. I'm attaching the image and I want to achieve something like that.
Where the Icon is clickable and on clicking the Icon it will display the other TextField.

**Here's the Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `suffixIcon`. If that doesn't behave how you'd expect, you can always use a `Stack`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Stack` Widget to do that. it works similar to a Row or a Column but its Stacks its children on top of each other.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

what you are trying to do this something like this,

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: (){
      //Code
    })
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stack Widget @Srilal Sachintha

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  children: <Widget>[
  TextFormField(),
  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: (){
  //Code
   })
 ],
),
```

or Use a `suffixIcon`. If that doesn't behave how you'd expect, you can always use a Stack. @